# Why $PSPACE!=Dtime(2^n)$?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, pspace

Why $PSPACE != Dtime(2^n)$? I can not see how padding argument can help here, how can it be proven?

Comment: I don't understand. What is the factorial of PSPACE?

Comment: @Jan Johannsen - I assume that it represents the "not equal ≠ " sign in C programming language

Answer (score 3):

If DTIME(2^n)=PSPACE then DTIME(2^poly)=PSPACE.

But, by the time hierarchy theorem, DTIME(2^n)⊊DTIME(2^poly)

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions.

Comment: Is there a meta discussion somewhere regarding this policy? Considering most off-topic questions are here by mistake (and presumably in good faith), I don't see how it hurts anyone to post answers before the question is migrated.